# I can rollback to the most recent revision

Tags: bug, revisions-list, rollbacks

I was just looking at the revision history of [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/100645/revisions), and was offered a link to rollback to the most recent revision of the question. Obviously, doing so would not change anything, since that post text is still the most recent revision. I did try clicking the rollback link; it refreshed the page without seemingly doing anything.

This seems to apply only to questions which have been closed and not subsequently edited.

[image]